# How to create a 2d grid?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

So I get this error when I try making my 2D grid. I get that it says it looks like I don't have 5 rows in my list. That was the error. Here is what I tried:

```
board = ["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"]

    def create_board(width, height, empty='O'):
        for x in range(5):
            board.append(board)
            return board
        return            

a = create_board(5, 5)
print(a)  # show "empty" board that was created
```

Comment: Why do you spend so much of your question mentioning Java, if your question has nothing to do with Java?

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
a_2d_list = [
             [r,o,w,1],
             [r,o,w,2],
             ...]
```

is that what you mean?

```
board = [["O", "O", "O", "O", "O"] for _ in range(0, 5)]
print "\n".join(map(" ".join,board))
```

Comment: Yes, but I mean with multiple rows and columns.

Comment: NOW you get the idea. Thanks. The expected output from that is basically what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
def create_board(width, height, empty='O'):
    return [[empty for _ in range(width)] for _ in range(height)]

board = create_board(3, 4)
print(board)  # show "empty" board that was created

board[1][1] = 'X'
print(board)  # show board after modification
```

Output:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O']]
[['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O']]
```

Comment: It seems like yours has two rows, which seems strange to me, but the output is basically what I would want. I would want the output to be 5x5 rows by columns. In each row, there would be one list. See what I mean?

Comment: There are two `print(board)` statements. The second is to show what's in the board after modifying one cell in it. The example creates a board of 4 rows, each containing a `list` of 3 items. If you want a 5x5 board, just call `create_board(5, 5)`.

Comment: what's in the "_" on line 2?